# How can I define the ManyToManyField name in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

I have this relationship

```
Class Item(models.Model):
   pass

Class Category(models.Model):
   items = models.ManyToManyField(Item)
```

I can define the field name as `items` for category and access it via `category.items` but I want to define a field name for Item too as `item.categories` rather than the default `item.category`

How can I achieve it?

#### Update

Tried

`items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, related_name = "categories")`

But I get

`TypeError: Direct assignment to the reverse side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use categories.set() instead.`

on `Item.object.create(**data)`

Comment: So you want to set related_name?

Comment: @TrueGopnik maybe but then I get this error `TypeError: Direct assignment to the reverse side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use categories.set() instead.` when I do `Item.object.create(**data)`

Comment: I tried:    `items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, related_name = "categories")`

Comment: Offtopic to your question, but wouldn't it make more sense to assign categories to item and not items to category?

Comment: doesn't really matter, I'd have the same issue the other way around

Comment: The error "*`TypeError: Direct assignment....`*" is an obvious one since the method to assign M2M is different. So, what's the point here?

Comment: @JPG without changing `related_name` it just works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `Item.objects.create()`, you need to omit the `categories` from the args. Then afterwards you can call `set()` to set the categories.

```
item = Item.objects.create()
item.categories.set(categories)
```

If you want to add to existing categories (rather than overwriting what’s there), call `add()` instead:

```
item = Item.objects.create()
item.categories.add(category)
```

Note: both `add()` and `set()` save the update to the database, so you don’t need to call `item.save()` afterwards

---

**EDIT**

It looks like with the default name, you can pass in a list of categories to the call to `create()` and it even seems like it works because you can access the list of categories in the attribute `category`:

```py
category = Category.objects.create()
item = Item.objects.create(category=[category])
print(item.category)
# output: [<Category: Category object(1)>]
```

The problem with this is `category` is not how you set or access category objects on an item, it’s `category_set`, and that’s empty.

To see this, after running the above code fetch the `item` from the database, you can see that the category is not associated with the item (it wasn’t saved):

```py
item = Item.objects.get(id=item.id)
print(item.category_set)
# output: []
```

(And if you try to do `item.category`, you get an attribute error.)

It’s confusing that Django lets you provide the `category` argument in a call to create() with the default related name,  but fails with an error when the related_name is set. IMO it should have an error in both cases, because clearly **passing an m2m list as an argument to `create()` does not work**: you have to call `set()` or `add()`.

---

Source: [Many-to-Many relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Comment: Why doesn't this happen with the default name? is there any way to have it working without the additional call?

Comment: With the default name I believe it’s `<model name>_set`, so before you added the `related_name=‘categories’` it would be `item.category_set.set(categories)` or `item.category_set.add(category)`.

Comment: As for working without the additional call, no, you’re going to have to call`.add()` or `.set()` to add m2m relations. The only exception I can think of is if you want to do raw queries, but that would be likely much more work than a single function call. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/sql/

Comment: with the default name it just works by doing `Item.object.create(**data)` without the call to `..._set` (with data containing a list of the the categories)

Comment: What exactly is in **data that you’re passing in?

Comment: just a dictionary like `{"name" : "asd", "categories" : [{"name": "category1"}, {"name": "category2"}]}`

Comment: My bet is it’s ignoring the categories argument. Have you checked to see if the item actually has those categories after calling create()?

Comment: yeah I had checked that

Comment: I see where the confusion is, please see edited answer above

Answer (score 0):

The thing about many to many field is not an actual field. If you take a look at the generated schema you wouldnt find the field as a column in either of the table. What happens in the back is django creates a `ItemCatagory` table.

```
class ItemCatagory(models.Model):
      item = modes.ForegnKeyField(Item, related_name="catagories", on_delete... )
      catagory = models.ForegnKeyField(Item, related_name="items", on_delete... )
```

`catagory.items` will give u the `ItemCatagory` `RelatedObject` and if u do `catagoty.items.all()` it will give u `QuerySet[ItemCatagory]`. so the default  `model.save()` method woont add those rship. so u would have to overide `save` method on either of the models.

Comment: Thanks, where would I have to define the save? would I have to define the middle class? Would I also have to overide the update method too?

Comment: you can do it like this 
`class Item(models.Model):`
    `...`
    `def save(self, **kwargs):`
         `update_fields = kwargs.get("update_fields")`
         `catagoy = update_fields.pop("catagoty")`
        `item = super().save(update_fields = update_fields, **kwargs)`
        `# do what u want here`
        `return item`

Comment: You don’t need to override the save method. Just like it says in the error, `Use categories.set() instead`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74659501/9638991).

Answer (score -1):

See, ManyToManyField can't make reverse relationship with related model as python is interpreted language, so it can't read model class of previous one. Instead, you can do one thing ...

```
# models.py

class Item(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item_name


class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name
```

After that, you can list down your requirements in views.py file.

```
# views.py

def get_items_by_categories(request):
    
    # Here, you will receive a set of items ...
    
    get_categories = Category.objects.all()

    # Filter out items with respect to categories ...

    get_items_list = [{"category": each.category_name, "items": each.items} for each in get_categories]

    return render(request, "categories.html", {"data": get_items_list})
```

Iterate your items with categories in categories.html file.

```
{% for each in data %}
    {% for content in each %}
        {{content.category}}
        {% for item in content.items.all %}
            {{item.item_name}}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I hope this solution will help you ..

Thank You !

Comment: nope, this doesn't answer my question.